# How can I read an HTML template from a file to send a mail with it using the JavaMail API?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, html-email

I've got an assigment to send HTML mail with the JavaMail API.
Here is a small part of my code:

```
MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

try {
    helper.setTo(recipients);
    helper.setSubject("Simple mail template");
    helper.setText("<html><body>Hi There</body><html>",html:true);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I've got an assigment to move the HTML in a separate file, and create a class to read that HTML template and send a mail with it.
Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: You're using the word "template", are you sure about that? Do you really want the separate file to be just a template (e.g. `<html><body>{{message}}</body><html>`, where `{{message}}` will dynamically be filled with a message), or do you just want the entire message in the file (e.g. `<html><body>Hi There</body><html>`)?

Comment: I want to message dynamically be filled with a message.With a list of some names.Thanks for asking that!

Comment: So, are you allowed to use another library (a template engine)?

Comment: Well,I'm not sure.What is your suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion is to use a template engine (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use a template engine

I've created a minimal example with [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org) as a template engine. You first wrote that you are using [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot) in your project, so I assume you can use it. I also assume you are using either [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) as a build tool.

---

## Adding the Thymeleaf dependency

Add the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency to your project. Are you using Maven or Gradle?

#### Maven

Your `pom.xml` dependencies should include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

Your `build.gradle` dependencies should include:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
```

---

## Configuring Thymeleaf in Spring Boot

Add the required `@Bean`s. Those are:

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver templateResolver()
{
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine()
{
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver());

    return templateEngine;
}
```

They can go into any class annotated with `@Configuration` (or `@SpringBootApplication`).

---

## Examples

Now, you can access your `TemplateEngine` from any class whose fields are injected by Spring.

```
@Component
public class SomeClass
{
    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public String generateMailHtml(String text)
    {
        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
        variables.put("mailtext", text);

        final String templateFileName = "mail"; //Name of the template file without extension
        String output = this.templateEngine.process(templateFileName, new Context(Locale.getDefault(), variables));

        return output;
    }
}
```

The `mail.html` should be located in the classpath (`resources/`) under `templates/`.

[image: Template file path]

And it should look like this:

```html
<html>
    <body data-th-text="${mailtext}"></body>
</html>
```

Your code snippet you posted could now look like this (`@Autowired` `SomeClass` as `someClass` in the class outside of the method):

```
MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

try {
    helper.setTo(recipients);
    helper.setSubject("Simple mail template");
    helper.setText(someClass.generateMailHtml("Hi There"), true);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course, change the examples according to your needs!

---

## Edit

You mentioned you need to fill the template "with a list of some names". This would be achieved like that:

```
public String generateMailHtml(List<String> names)
{
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
    variables.put("names", names);

    final String templateFileName = "mail"; //Name of the template file without extension
    String output = this.templateEngine.process(templateFileName, new Context(Locale.getDefault(), variables));

    return output;
}
```

`mail.html`

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li data-th-each="name : ${names}" data-th-text="${name}"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Read more about `data-th-each` / `th:each` [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach). Note: You can use `data-th-` and `th:` interchangably, though `data-th-` is more HTML5-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I like [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) approach, just generate app with jhipster.  You get good example. Short part of their code

Template message save like resourses in your project:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title th:text="#{email.activation.title}">Activation</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/favicon.ico|}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p th:text="#{email.activation.greeting(${user.login})}">
            Dear
        </p>
        <p th:text="#{email.activation.text1}">
            Your  account has been created, please click on the URL below to activate it:
        </p>
        <p>
            <a th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/#/activate?key=${user.activationKey}|}"
               th:text="@{|${baseUrl}/#/activate?key=${user.activationKey}|}">Activation Link</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="#{email.activation.text2}">Regards, </span>
            <br/>
            <em th:text="#{email.signature}">Innovation Development HUB.</em>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Email sender before config credential and preferences for send email in yaml file

```
@Service
public class MailService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailService.class);

    private static final String USER = "user";

    private static final String BASE_URL = "baseUrl";

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public MailService(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties, JavaMailSender javaMailSender,
            MessageSource messageSource, SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {

        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    @Async
    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean isMultipart, boolean isHtml) {
        log.debug("Send email[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
            isMultipart, isHtml, to, subject, content);

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(content, isHtml);
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            log.debug("Sent email to User '{}'", to);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
            } else {
                log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}': {}", to, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Async
    public void sendEmailFromTemplate(User user, String templateName, String titleKey) {
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(user.getLangKey());
        Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariable(USER, user);
        context.setVariable(BASE_URL, jHipsterProperties.getMail().getBaseUrl());
        String content = templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
        String subject = messageSource.getMessage(titleKey, null, locale);
        sendEmail(user.getEmail(), subject, content, false, true);

    }

    @Async
    public void sendActivationEmail(User user) {
        log.debug("Sending activation email to '{}'", user.getEmail());
        sendEmailFromTemplate(user, "activationEmail", "email.activation.title");
    }

    @Async
    public void sendCreationEmail(User user) {
        log.debug("Sending creation email to '{}'", user.getEmail());
        sendEmailFromTemplate(user, "creationEmail", "email.activation.title");
    }

    @Async
    public void sendPasswordResetMail(User user) {
        log.debug("Sending password reset email to '{}'", user.getEmail());
        sendEmailFromTemplate(user, "passwordResetEmail", "email.reset.title");
    }
}
```

And you need SpringTemplateEngine

```
public class SpringTemplateEngine extends TemplateEngine implements MessageSourceAware, InitializingBean {
    private static final SpringStandardDialect SPRINGSTANDARD_DIALECT = new SpringStandardDialect();
    private MessageSource messageSource = null;
    private MessageSource templateEngineMessageSource = null;

    public SpringTemplateEngine() {
        super.clearDialects();
        super.addDialect(SPRINGSTANDARD_DIALECT);
    }

    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    public void setTemplateEngineMessageSource(MessageSource templateEngineMessageSource) {
        this.templateEngineMessageSource = templateEngineMessageSource;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        SpringMessageResolver springMessageResolver = new SpringMessageResolver();
        springMessageResolver.setMessageSource(this.templateEngineMessageSource == null ? this.messageSource : this.templateEngineMessageSource);
        super.setDefaultMessageResolvers(Collections.singleton(springMessageResolver));
    }

    protected final void initializeSpecific() {
        Configuration configuration = this.getConfiguration();
        Map<String, IDialect> dialects = configuration.getDialects();
        Iterator var3 = dialects.values().iterator();

        IDialect dialect;
        do {
            if (!var3.hasNext()) {
                throw new ConfigurationException("When using " + SpringTemplateEngine.class.getSimpleName() + ", at least one of the configured dialects must be or extend " + SpringStandardDialect.class.getName() + ".");
            }

            dialect = (IDialect)var3.next();
        } while(!(dialect instanceof SpringStandardDialect));

        this.initializeSpringSpecific();
    }

    protected void initializeSpringSpecific() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a word about Thymeleaf?

Comment: Yes of cource needs org.thymeleaf.spring4 and

Comment: What if i do not need a dynamic binding and just simply need to refer to a html file located in resources , what would be the approach